# Ember data fixtures and view bindings. Are these bugs?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to implement a to do list, which is made up of a to do view, with a nested entries view that contains multiple entry views. Each entry has the ability to be deleted and therefore removed from the container view.

When wired up to my Rails app, this *almost* works. When the delete button is clicked (or App.ToDoEntry.find(x).deleteRecord() is triggered in the console) the instance is set to isDirty=true, but the entry is still visible in the view.

To try and test what is going on, I've made a separate jsfiddle using Fixtures to see if I can make it work in isolation and in doing so I think I might have also stumbled upon a bug with fixtures in Ember data.

Firstly, here's the Rails + Ember app that I've been working on:

**Rails**

```
class ToDo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :to_do_entries, dependent: :destroy  
  attr_accessible :is_deleted, :is_staging, :is_template, :title
  validates_presence_of :title
end

class ToDoSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :title

  has_many :to_do_entries, embed: :objects
end

class ToDoEntry < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :to_do
  attr_accessible :completed_at, :is_deleted, :priority, :title
  validates_presence_of :to_do, :title
end

class ToDoEntrySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :to_do_id,
             :title,
             :priority
end
```

**Ember**

```
/*---------------*/
/* Application   */
/*---------------*/

PLURAL_MAPPINGS = {"to_do_entry": "to_do_entries"};

App = Em.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#content',
  store: DS.Store.create({
    adapter:  DS.RESTAdapter.create({ plurals: PLURAL_MAPPINGS }),
    revision: 4
  })
});

/*---------------*/
/* Controllers   */
/*---------------*/

App.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  destroy: function() {
    this.transaction = App.store.transaction();
    this.transaction.add(this.get('content'));
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) { 
      this.get('content').deleteRecord();
      this.transaction.commit();
      App.router.transitionTo('todo');
    }
    else{
      this.transaction.rollback();
      this.transaction = null;
    }
  }
});

App.Todo_entriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

App.Todo_entryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  destroy: function() {
    this.transaction = App.store.transaction();
    this.transaction.add(this.get('content'));
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) { 
      this.get('content').deleteRecord();
      this.transaction.commit();
      App.router.transitionTo('todo');
    }
    else{
      this.transaction.rollback();
      this.transaction = null;
    }
  }
});

/*--------*/
/* Models */
/*--------*/

App.ToDo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  group: DS.belongsTo('App.Group'),
  to_do_entries: DS.hasMany('App.ToDoEntry', { embedded: true })
});

App.ToDoEntry = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  to_do_id: DS.attr('number'),
  priority: DS.attr('number'),
  todo: DS.belongsTo('App.ToDo')
});

/*-------*/
/* Views */
/*-------*/ 

App.TodoView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app/templates/todo'
});

App.Todo_entriesView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app/templates/todo_entries'
});

App.Todo_entryView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app/templates/todo_entry',
  destroyEntry: function() {
    console.log('Todo_entryView - destroyEntry');
    this.get('controller').destroy();
  },
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    this.set(
      'controller',
      App.Todo_entryController.create({ content: this.get('content') })
    );
  }  
});  

/*-----------*/
/* Templates */
/*-----------*/ 

todo.hbs

<article>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>  
  <div class="widget_links">
    <a {{action destroy target="view"}}>Delete</a>
  </div>
  {{outlet}}
</article>

todo_entries.hbs

{{#if isLoading}}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{{else}}
  <ul class="list">
  {{collection contentBinding="content" itemViewClass="App.Todo_entryView"}}
  </ul>
{{/if}}

todo_entry.hbs

<li>
{{#if isLoading}}
  Loading...
{{else}}
  {{view.content.id}}) {{view.content.title}} Priority: {{view.content.priority}}
  <a {{action destroyEntry href="true" target="view"}}>Delete</a>
{{/if}}
</li>

/*--------*/
/* Router */
/*--------*/

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash',
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      connectOutlets: function(router) {
        var todo = App.ToDo.find(21);
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('todo', todo);
        var todoController = router.get('todoController');
        todoController.connectOutlet('todo_entries', todoController.get("to_do_entries"));
      }
    })
  })
}); 

App.initialize();
```

As mentioned above, this is very close to working, but frustratingly doesn't seem to remove the entry from the view. Am I doing something obvious wrong here, or is this a bug?

**A bug with fixtures?**

Secondly, I made a version that does work, using fixtures. However it appears that the fixture data doesn't load unless App.ToDo.find() (i.e. a findAll) is requested.

Here are two examples:

**Single to do, failing delete.**

http://jsfiddle.net/danielrosewarne/vDGhe/1/

The first loads a single to do, with it's associated entries. When you click 'Delete' you get the warning correctly and it invalidates the object. However, the entry remains in the view.

*Note, if you view with console on you'll see that the isDirty state is set to true.*

**Multiple to dos, everything is ok**

http://jsfiddle.net/danielrosewarne/LeLyy/1/

The second lists all of the to do records in an index view, thereby pre-loading the data it seems. When you click through to the to do to see it's entries the delete works as you would expect. (Incidentally, this also works if you just do App.ToDo.find() in the console in example 1.)

This feels to me like it's a bug in Ember data, am I right or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: I haven't had time to go through your fiddles, but I noticed that you're on revision 4 of Ember data. They made commits last night that bring the revision up to number 7. Unless you have a specific reason not to I would suggest using most recent build of ember-data. You might find that issues like this are already taken care of.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.

I've updated to the latest versions of both Ember and Ember data and that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Specifically with Fixtures it appears that if you don't load all of the parent, then the children can't be deleted when they are rendered. Very strange.

Comment: Looks like you're not mapping the `primaryKey` of the ToDoEntry in your store's adapter. Look at the changes in R5 of https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md for more details.

Comment: Hi Tim. I've given that a try, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I was under the impression that you only had to set the primaryKey mapping, if you were using anything other than id as the field name (guid for example). If not, it would use id by default?

Comment: I can confirm that the default `primaryKey` is `id`. It's possible there are bugs with fixtures. I know that you can't really properly save records with fixtures for one.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug. I've logged it over here --> https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/438

Answer (score 0):

The transaction.commit() is asynchronous, yet you are immediately transitioning to another state within the route. The view is getting updated before the transaction has finished. I believe this is the issue, or at least it is one issue. Ember is very tricky when it comes to asynchronous operations. Try this:

```
App.Todo_entryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  destroy: function() {
    this.transaction = App.store.transaction();
    this.transaction.add(this.get('content'));
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) { 
      this.get('content').deleteRecord();
      this.get('content').one('didDelete', function() {
        App.router.transitionTo('todo');
      });
      this.transaction.commit();
    }
    else{
      this.transaction.rollback();
      this.transaction.delete();
    }
  }
});
```

Also, this whole function should be in the router, not the controller, as it changes state. You are burying the state change when you stick it in the router.

Cheers.